# .net Oracle Transaction passed to class byRef

Tags: .net, oracle, odp.net

I have a process where I pass my oracle connection and transaction byRef.  All my inserts/deletes seem to be working fine.  However one of the updates seems to run through just fine, however the data in the database is not updated.

I am wondering if I am disposing the qry object to soon before I commit and thats the reason.  This is my first attempt at using the oracle transaction and all the samples I found online, all seem to do it per method.  I need to make sure it runs through my whole process before I commit otherwise I want to rollback.

```
Using conn As New OracleConnection(myObject.ConnectionString)
    conn.Open()
    Dim myTrans As OracleTransaction
    myTrans = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)

    Try
        If ClassName.Insert(conn, myTrans) THEN
        'Insert Happened
        End If

        If ClassName.Update(conn, myTrans) THEN

        End If

        If ClassName.Delete(conn, myTrans)  THEN

        End If

        MyTrans.Commit()
    Catch ex As Exception
        myTrans.Rollback()
    Finally

        'Close connection
        If conn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed AndAlso conn.State <> ConnectionState.Connecting Then
            conn.Close()
            conn.Dispose()
        End If

    End Try 
End Using
```

Here is an simple example of my class update function..

```
 Public Function Update(ByRef conn As OracleConnection, ByRef myTrans As OracleTransaction) As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean = False
    Try
        Dim sql As String = ""
        sql = sql & "UPDATE TABLENAME "
        sql = sql & " SET"
        sql = sql & " xyz = :xyz"

        sql = sql & " WHERE id = :id"

        Using qry As New OracleCommand(sql, conn)
            qry.Transaction = myTrans
            qry.Parameters.Add("id", OracleDbType.Decimal, Me.ID, ParameterDirection.Input)
            qry.ExecuteNonQuery()
            result = True
            qry.Dispose()
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
    End Try
    Return result

End Function
```

No error happens in the update, the record is never updated in the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding

qry.BindByName = True

Since my ID parameter was being set first, but in the query it was last (In the where section of the query).

Thank you again for your advice.  I will look into the systems.transactions.  This was my first attempt at using the transactions and firs time using Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know VB.net very well, but I do know that the OracleCommand constructor wants the transaction as the third parameter.  In C# it would look like this:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, connection, transaction);
```

Since the transaction is an object, I don't think passing it as a reference is necessary.  In C# this wouldn't matter unless you cloned the object, which sounds like a really bad idea for a database transaction object.

All that said, if you don't use the transaction, then it should simply bypass your open transaction and essentially autocommit.

I think your code is throwing and catching an exception.  Your try/catch is just masking the real problem, unless I've missed the boat.  You have two parameters in your SQL but only bound one.  Where is :xyz bound?  I suspect that's the issue, but if you want the transaction to be used (so you can commit at the end), make sure you include it in your OracleCommand constructor.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things you can do.  For one, ExecuteNonQuery normally returns the rows affected.  It could just be that your where clause didn't identify any records and the update affected 0 rows.  If you're sure that an update should have occurred, you could confirm that ExecuteNonQuery returned > 0 and throw an error other wise.  At the very least set "result=false" in that case.

Two, you could/should rethrow the error in your catch after you rollback.

As a related sidebar, I would just use System.Transactions and the TransactionScope object.  Then you don't need to pass the transaction or the connection.  You do need to make sure the OraMTSRecovery Service is running in that case, but that comes with all the ODP.net installs anyway.